# How do I configure a Debian so that multiple users can do administration, but not see each others' personal files?

Tags: linux, debian, sudo, administration

I'm looking to set up a server to share with a group of people. The machine will run Debian GNU/Linux, and we would like to allow multiple people to do administration tasks (in particular installing, updating and configuring software), but we would not like to give everyone of those administrators read access to everybody's home directories, so giving them some direct way of becoming `root` is not the optimal solution.

I assume there may be a well-tested way to do this, which I imagine could involve using `sudo` and setting `sudoers` properly. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution that would best ensure that everyone's home directories are private is to encrypt the home directories. I could be wrong but I think it would be pretty difficult to get the configuration you want without encryption. If others have physical access to your machine they can always read your files if they really want to (boot a live OS, mount the drive, and read away). So I think encryption would be your best bet.

I'm not familiar with every method for encrypting one's hard drive but for example Ubuntu gives you the option to encrypt your home drive during installation using eCryptfs. This lives on top of the file system so you don't have to have separate partitions, etc. When you log in the file system is unlocked. So the user can't tell that his home directory is encrypted, the user uses the system just as they always have. The encryption doesn't have to get in your way. I'm not familiar with how hard this is to setup.

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, allow those people to run `apt-get` and `dpkg` as root using `/etc/sudoers`.

I'm not sure whether this opens up a possibility for messing with other users' directories though (say, via crafting the environment in a special way before running that programs). `sudo` should take care of that but I'd ask on the `debian-security` list if you're not really sure.